# Flash Builder keeps changing perspectives. Need to reset

Tags: eclipse, actionscript-3, flash-builder

I have accidentally setup my Flash Builder to change to the **Debug Perspective** when debugging my applications. This is useful when the application crashes, but not every run.

I can´t seem to find the settings to change it back to default. Anyone know where to look?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under Window --> Preferences in Run/Debug --> Perspectives there is an option there "Open the associated perspective when an application suspends". The default is "Prompt" which is what will ask you if you want to switch to the Debug Perspective when the application encounters something. Alternatively you could set it to Never which means you will always have to switch perspectives manually.

Cheers